# onSubmit Trigger: GetEditResponseUrl of Form Fails to Execute Sometimes

Tags: google-apps-script

I want users to be able to edit their responses from this Google form, so i want to place the edit response url on the 14th column in the sheet of the responses.

I set up a trigger, onSubmit. Every time a user submits the form, this function runs. The issue is, sometimes it works and sets the edit URL on the 14th column. But sometimes it throws an error: Cannot call method "getEditResponseUrl" of undefined.

Meaning, the line: "var rs = f.getResponses(timeStamp)[0];" fails to get the responses after the timestamp.

I think it has something to do with getting the Timestamp and latency on Google's end. I feel like, the function gets the timestamp from (e) but it doesnt see any responses after that timestamp.

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var rng = e.range; //Collects active range for event
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//collects active spreadsheet object

  var fUrl = ss.getFormUrl();//gets form url linked with active spreadsheet
  var f = FormApp.openByUrl(fUrl);//opens form using form url

   var timeStamp = new Date(e.namedValues.Timestamp[0]);//gets the timestamp of the form response
  var rs = f.getResponses(timeStamp)[0]; //gets the first response after the 

    var row = e.range.getRow();

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("All"); // responses sheet
    sheet.getRange(row, 14).setValue(rs.getEditResponseUrl());

}
```

Comment: Have you compared the timestamp from the event object to the timestamp in the Form?  I've heard of cases where they might be 1 second different.

Comment: Yes. I do notice that sometimes in the google sheets its a second off from the actual event object timestamp.

Comment: You could use `Utilitles.sleep(5000);` which pauses the code for 5 seconds to determine if it's a latency issue.  If you ever get multiple Form submissions at the same time, that could be a problem.

Comment: yeah, this form is used by atleast 30 people. Alot of the times, the forms are submitted at the same time. It will be an issue. Thank you for your help Sandy, i'll try to see if theres a workaround or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Not exactly sure why this way works and the other methods dont. Maybe because im getting the timestamp directly from the sheet,so its not off by 1 second. Previously, by using the e object the timestamp would be off by a second.

On submit Trigger:

```
function onSubmit(e){
editBillingFormURLEncoded(e.range.getRow()); //pass in row to function
}


function editBillingFormURLEncoded(row){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SheetID).getSheets()[0]; //Open First Sheet in Spreadsheet
  var vals = ss.getRange(row,1,1,15).getValues();
 var timeStamp = vals[0][0]; //first value of sheet is the timestamp

   var googleFormUrl = ss.getFormUrl(); //get form linked to the spreadsheet
   var googleForm = FormApp.openByUrl(googleFormUrl); //FormApp
try{  
  var formResponse = googleForm.getResponses(timeStamp)[0]; //get last response after timestamp
   var responseUrl = formResponse.getEditResponseUrl(); //get the edit form URL
  ss.getRange(row, 14).setValue(responseUrl); //setting the responseURL Value on 14th column of sheet
  }
  catch(error){
  ss.getRange(row, 14).setValue("Failed");
  }
}
```